# how to close WPF page like window

Tags: wpf

I want to close a WPF page but `Close()` for the page does not work.  In a WPF window `this.Close()` closes the window but in a WPF page, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

A page isn't a Window, and as such, it's not directly Closable.  From the [documentation for Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.aspx), a *Page* is intended to be "page of content that can be navigated to and **hosted by**" ...

You'll need to get a reference to the Page's host, and close it.  If you're hosting this Page inside of a Window, you can close that Window.

Answer (score 0):

replace the content of the container controller where you placed the page with some other or clear the container content